# iPad's Safari have problems on rendering jpg as background-image?

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad

This is my code :

## HTML

```
<div class="sfondo-interne-8601">
    <div style="height:1200px; width:900px;">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.sfondo-interne-8601
{
    background-image:url('http://www.deviantart.com/download/247331565/moonlit_tears_by_lifesequencebreak-d439699.png') !important;   
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center top;
}
```

Well, try to create a page an test it on iPad : it works well (the image is png).

Now, try to change the image with a jpg (I already choose one for you [here](http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/9540/tifacloudandsephirothya.jpg)). You will notice that the new image will be resized (not sure about which rules) and centered in the center/top of the whole html document.

Why? And how can I fix it? Is there any limitation on ipad?

JUST noticed that if I use .jpg slower than 1150px (as height) it works as well. A Safari's bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS, [jpeg images of over 2MP get subsampled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) (look under "resource limits"), effectively altering the dimensions of the image.

I'd speculate this would not manifest so obviously with CSS `background-size` set to `contain` or `cover` (it would still happen, but since the aspect ration would not be affected and the background sizing algorithm would still be run)

If you want for the subsampled background image to keep rendering at its original dimensions, you can add `background-size: 1920px 1200px`: [before](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/v9Ax7/1/) and [after](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/v9Ax7/3/).

Comment: over 2MP? That's not over 2MP!That jpeg is 389,37kB. In fact, saving the jpeg 1900x1200 at 30% of quality I got the same problem... so it's a dimension pain! Setting :cover seems works. Hope it don't hurt IE :)

Comment: @markzzz: the 389.37KB *file* size is irrelevant since the *image* size is over 2MP: 1900px * 1200px = 2280000px = 2.28MP

Comment: I also noticed that background-size "change" the size of the image, if I resize the browser. Damnnnn....

Comment: @markzzz: that's the desired behaviour for those particular values (for some reason I've assumed you're after them ಠ_ಠ). You should ignore them and instead have a look at [mdn docos on image resizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Scaling_background_images)

Comment: Uhm! No! What I want is that the image is centered in the browser, not resized. So I think I have to avoid background-size. Any other solution?

Comment: In fact what I want is the standard behaviour of background-position:center top; that works on iPad :) I think the only way is to convert jpg in PNG, my god...

Comment: Yeah, that's the same of `background-size: auto auto;` but on the iPad it still doesnt works...

Comment: @markzzz: when I navigate directly to [fiddle 1](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ovfiddle/v9Ax7/1/show/) and [fiddle 3](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ovfiddle/v9Ax7/3/show/) on an iPad3, I see the difference. I don't know what you're trying though

Comment: Do you see differences between http://fiddle.jshell.net/ovfiddle/v9Ax7/3/show/ and http://fiddle.jshell.net/v9Ax7/4/show/ ? Also : I don't know the real size of the image, I have many images that will load :) I should use a JS function that add background-size at loading...(if I can get the dimension from a background-size)

Comment: Also : what's about PNG? What are the MAX size/MB?